# How to Capture Dialog (Swing) Focus Lost Event in Scala?

Tags: swing, scala, dialog, focus

While I can listenTo(button) FocusLost event, I don't seem to be able to capture FocusLost event in a Dialog (Scala's Swing Component). How do I do that? I tried adding Publisher trait to Dialog but nothing works. Any advice is great here.

Thanks

/lim/

Answer (score 0):

You can alsways work with the underlying Java Swing objects. Call `.peer` on your `Dialog` object and receive a `JDialog` object.

Comment: I am aware that I can work with the peer instance but I try to work according to Swing Scala "rules" as closely as possible unless it is not possible

Comment: I've tried around in the REPL and could not obtain a `FocusLost` from a `Dialog` or a `Frame` directly. Also adding a `Panel` as intermediate layer and listening to the panel did not work. Only listening directly to the `Button` worked as you described. This does not mean there is no Scala solution. But anyway my given answer works, even when you don't want to follow it (what I can understand).

Comment: This is solution is closer to what I want, http://groups.google.com/group/scala-user/browse_thread/thread/3228fdc6d9f8f300